# How to properly declare a self-referencing template type?

Tags: c++, templates

How do I declare a templated type that refers to itself?

```
template <class T = Animal> class Animal
{
public:
    T getChild ();
}
```

With this, I get a compiler error concerning a missing type specifier. I tried to forward-declare `Animal`, without success.

I am trying to impose a type constraint. A `Lion` can only have a `Lion` as a child, a `Bear` has a `Bear`, and so on.

**EDIT**

I'll post part of the actual class. It is a template for classes that can appear in a linked list:

```
template <class T = Linked<T> > class Linked
{
private:
    T* m_prev;
    T* m_next;
}
```

I want to enforce that the class can only point to object of the same class (or a subclass).

Comment: This strikes me as a rather weird use of templates.  What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a node in a specialized linked list that holds pointers to other instances of its type. In Java generics, this works without a hitch.

Comment: That seems like a need that inheritance would fill more correctly than template types.

Comment: If it holds pointers to other instances of the same type, why do you need a template argument?

Comment: It works in Java because, e.g. a `Collection` is a `Collection<Object>`.

Comment: @Jen: perhaps you should post what "works without a hitch" in Java generics so that we can help you understand how to write that in C++.

Comment: I've posted an excerpt of the actual class.

Comment: @Jen: I think you're trying to make sure that the type used in the template is derived from `Animal`, but that's not what it does.  This is not possible (nor necessary) in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do something like a linked list is:

```
template <class T> class Linked
{
private:
    Linked<T>* m_prev;
    Linked<T>* m_next;
}
```

Does this work for you, and if not, what are you trying to accomplish that can't be done this way?

Comment: Now comes the inevitable memory corruption followup question since the template class lacks a copy c'tor, copy-assignment operator, and destructor. :-P

Answer (score 5):

The OP has been answered but I want to chime in because the immediate cause of the problem is not recursion, as others claim. The simplest reason this wouldn't work is that class templates are *not* types. They are templates. Similarly, function templates are not functions either. So all of this is nonsensical:

```
template<typename T> int function_template(int);
typedef int function_type(int);
void eats_a_function(function_type&); // needs a reference to function

std::vector< std::vector > vec0; // std::vector is not a type
std::vector< std::list > vec1; // std::list is not a type
eats_a_function(function_template); // function_template is not a function
```

Notice that in the `vec1` case, `std::list` is not related to `std::vector`. The template is fully defined (assuming header inclusion) at the point of instantiation. It still won't work.

Instead, the following works:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec2; // std::vector<int> is a type
std::vector< std::list<double> > vec3; // std::list<double> is a type
eats_a_function(function_template<long>); // function_template<long> is a function
```

Notice that in the vec2 case, it's fine to pass an instantiation of the template itself.

---

For the record, a toy solution to the toy problem on writing a template that refers to itself, using the proverbial layer of indirection:

```
// expects a template that expects a type
template<template<class> class T> struct indirection {};

// forward decl. for defaulting the parameter
template<typename T> struct recursive;

// template that expects a type
template<typename T = indirection<recursive> > struct recursive {};
```

Not terribly powerful given the few things that are possible with a template (the `T` parameter inside `indirection`). It's of course possible to write a `rebind`-style metafunction that returns an instantiation of `T`.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you need to specify some type parameter to Animal in your typename definition, or else it would be an "infinite recursion" in the type construction:

```
template<class T> class Animal;//you'll need this forward declaration

template <class T = Animal<int> > class Animal //int is just an example
{
public:
    T getPrey ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a template class wherein the template type is the class itself.  This is a logical recursion that your compiler can't mitigate.  Since templates require the compiler to construct the object when a specific typing is encountered ( say Animal ), you have to have a complete definition of the template type.  Otherwise, the compiler will recursively try to construct objects.  Since your object self-references, this will be an non-terminating recursion.

This use-case seems much more appropriate for inheritance than for templates.

Doing this will let you compile:
    template  class Animal
    {
    public:
        T getPrey ();
    }

Or, if you really wan't a default argument:

```
template <class T=Cheetah> class Animal
{
public:
    T getPrey ();
}
```

Yet, cheetah must not use itself or Animal as one of its potential template types.

Comment: *"Since templates require the compiler to construct the object when a specific typing is encountered..., you have to have a complete definition of the template type"* - [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) seems to indicate otherwise (if I am parsing things correctly). The definition can come later than the declaration.

Comment: This is not infinitely recursive because it is dynamically creating the parent class